# How to teach R find the texlive directory when using rstudio?

Tags: linux, rstudio

My operating system is linux mint 15, and I recently installed the texlive 2013. After installation, I appended the search path for texlive to ~/.bashrc

```
# set PATH
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH

# set MANPATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH

# set INFOPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

Then I could locate cmds such as *pdflatex* on xterm. However, when I wanted to use the pkg *Sweave* in rstudio, it always prompted that *No Tex installation detected*. I examined the `$PATH` in rstudio by `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and found out that the `texlive/` directory was not appended to `$PATH`. So I guessed the problem was that the environment of Xsession doesn't take `~/.bashrc` into considration. How to address this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently set up a configuration like yours.

The most correct solution is to put those lines into `~/.profile` (or `/etc/profile`, for all users, as I did); this way all processes will inherit that PATH, not only those derived from `bash`.

Comment: yes, I already solve the problem by adding the code `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/",sep=":"))` in `~/.Rprofile`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. R Studio runs in a shell that doesn't pay attention to the usual startup scripts. As far as I can tell, the appropriate place to change them globally (for all users) is `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site` and for individual users, `$HOME/.Renviron`. (On my system, `R_HOME` is `/usr/lib/R`.)

Run `?Startup` in the R Studio console for more details.

Comment: This is correct, I don't think RStudio will check `~./profile`. Note also that you have to escape dollar-sign quoted variables with {}, so the line you want to add at the end of `Renviron.site` is: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}`