# R Markdown 'awesome cv' fails to knit: revision 70721 of the texlive-scripts package seems to be older than the local installation

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

When I try to knit the ‘awesomecv’ template, or any of the cv templates in R, I am getting this error:

> tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 70721 of the texlive-scripts package) seems to be older than the local installation (rev 70727 of texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.

I’m using WIndows 11, R 4.3.3, RStudio 2023.12.0 Build 369, vitae  0.5.3, and tinytex 0.50.

Any suggestions? Know of any other cv packages? I’m told ‘package ‘datadrivencv’ is not available for this version of R’.

I tried:

- The debugging tips suggested by Yihui.org, here:https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging, That is, upgrading all packages, and reinstalling tinytex
- Downgrading to vitae 0.5.3 instead of 0.5.4, as suggested here:  https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/248
- Reading this Substack solution, but it’s over my head - and old: [TinyTex errors within RMarkdown (Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740245/tinytex-errors-within-rmarkdown-local-tex-live-2021-is-older-than-remote-repo)
- as well as related 'questions already on Stack Overflow to see if your question is a duplicate.'